# Elasticsearch slow log

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elk, elastic-beats

I am implemented slow log queries in elasticsearch and shipping them to elasticsearch monitoring server using filebeat elasticsearch module. I am using default template called filebeat, basically using default settings.

The problem I am getting is the logs are indexing in elasticsearch the field names are doubling up like elasticsearch.slowlog.elasticsearch.slowlog.took, as you can check that elasticsearch.slowlog.took become elasticsearch.slowlog.elasticsearch.slowlog.took.

What i am doing wrong and what is the solution?

I am attaching one screenshot how fields are creating on elasticsearch.

[image]

What I am trying is keep the field as it is. like elasticsearch.slowlog.took.

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: Filebeat-8.8.2 (Docker version)

Comment: What about Elasticsearch, same version 8.8.2?

Comment: Yes, Elasticsearch version is also same